# error in base64 decoding in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, utf-8, base64, decode

I am trying to implement decode some encoded text like---

```
  new_parsed_plain_text="QWNjZXNzIGZvciBsZXNzIHNlY3Vy5lZ CBvbg0KDQo....so on"

  puts  Base64.decode64(new_parsed_plain_text)

 output is 
Hi Debasish,
 You recently changed your security settings so that your Google Account

 .
```

..........so on

but problem is

```
    if body.include? "Encoding: base64"
     pos = body.enum_for(:scan,/base64/).map { Regexp.last_match.begin(0) }
     l_pos=body.enum_for(:scan, /\/html/).map { Regexp.last_match.begin(0) }
     actual_pos=pos.first.to_i
     last_pos=l_pos.first.to_i-50
     new_parsed_plain_text = body[actual_pos..last_pos] 
     puts  Base64.decode64(new_parsed_plain_text)
```

the output is 
      m▒▒66W72f▒"▒W726V7W&R2▒2&VV▒GW&▒VB▒▒РРРФ▒▒FV&6▒6▒▒Х▒▒R&V6V▒Fǒ6▒▒vVB▒▒W"6V7W&▒G▒6WGF▒▒w26▒F▒B▒▒W"v▒▒v▒R66▒V▒@ЦFV&6▒6▒▒▒GW7G&▒g▒#dv▒▒▒▒6▒▒▒2▒▒▒▒▒vW"&▒FV7FVB'▒▒▒FW&▒6V7W&▒G▒Ч7F▒F&G2▒РХ▒V6R&Rv&RF▒B▒B▒2▒▒rV6▒W"f▒"▒GF6▒W"F▒'&V▒▒▒F▒▒▒W Ц66▒V▒B▒▒▒R6▒▒▒R▒▒W"66▒V▒B6fW"v▒▒'▒V▒F▒▒▒rF▒▒26▒▒vR▒W&PУƇGG3▒▒▒wwr▒v▒▒v▒R▒6▒▒▒6WGF▒▒w2▒6V7W&▒G▒▒▒W776V7W&V3▒▒F▒V▒7v▒F6▒▒▒pЧF▒2▒FR'▒v▒▒v▒R7V6▒2v▒▒▒F▒66W72▒▒W"66▒V▒B▒РТ▒F▒▒wB&V6▒v

how can solve this problem?can any one help me?

Comment: what are you trying to do in the second code block? What does the body actually look like?

Comment: I am trying parse mail which contains plain text which come through IMAP with encoded form

Comment: can you add the request content? Its hard to tell where the problem is without seeing the real content of the request

Comment: i am already solved this problem...this problem come over by removing the space before whole string